# Magento 1.9 custom module version not upgrading?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, upgrade-script

Am trying to upgrade a module. The core_resource table is not updating and sql resource is not running. I have tried lots of possibilities.

My config.xml

```
 <modules>
  <ITwebexperts_Request4quote>
        <version>2.2.0.20180430</version>
    </ITwebexperts_Request4quote>
 </modules>
```

My upgrade script name

```
  mysql4-upgrade-2.2.20170523-2.2.0.20180430.php
```

current row in core_resource

```
   request4quote_setup | 2.2.20170523 | 2.2.20170523
```

please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to upgrade module version from **2.2.20170523**, the upgraded version should be like **2.2.20180523** or **2.2.20170524**.

You have used ***2.2.0*.20180430** (Note the **0** in 2.2.0.***), which makes the version number less than the version **`2.2.20170523`**.

I hope my answer is clear to you.

Comment: Great to know.. Can you upvote my answer if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

You must have to used max version number in upgrade file. Here you have used "20170523" version number which is less than "20180430" version number. Try to upgrade file like below:-

```
mysql4-upgrade-2.2.20170524-2.2.20170523.php
```

config.xml file:-

```
<modules>
  <ITwebexperts_Request4quote>
        <version>2.2.20170524</version>
    </ITwebexperts_Request4quote>
 </modules>
```

I think it should be help you. If still your version not upgrade then try to remove extension entry from "core_resource" table and then check. Thanks.

Comment: Actaully i didn't get you. Usually we name the upgrade file like : mysql4-upgrade-{old version} - {new version}.php right ? my current version is '2.2.20170523' and i want to upgrade this to latest.

Comment: i have edited my answer. please check it. thanks.